# SQL Server - Where CONTAINS (Field, SUBQUERY)

Tags: sql-server, contains

I've two tables:

```
SELECT FIELD_A,
       FIELD_A1
FROM TABLE A
```

AND

```
 SELECT FIELD_B
    FROM TABLE B
```

All the fields are from nvarchar type. And what I'm trying to do is:

```
   SELECT FIELD_A,
           FIELD_A1
    FROM TABLE A
    WHERE CONTAINS (FIELD_A, SELECT FIELD_B FROM TABLE B)
```

Basically I have in Field_B part of the word that I've in Field_A. For example:

- Field_A is SQLSERVER_DEVELOPMENT_DATABASE
- Field_B is SQLSERVER

How can I do this using SQL Server?

Thanks!

Comment: FIELD_A is a fixed value?

Comment: No... it can change. It can be a lot of characters and I don't know the position of the Field_B

Comment: It's not clear to me, are you trying to find existing pairs of values?

Comment: No, I'm trying to see if the Field_B exists inside Field_A. In the example that I provide Field_B exists in Field_A

Comment: Could you add a sample example and the desired result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `PATINDEX` to check whether the field in table B contains what you're looking for, like this:

```
SELECT FIELD_A, FIELD_A1
FROM A
    INNER JOIN B
        ON PATINDEX( '%'+ FIELD_B +'%', FIELD_A ) > 0
```